# There is an error in XML Document (0,0)

Tags: c#, xml, soap, ssis, deserialization

I have spent countless hours working on this issue, and have tried so many different things. Some background... I am working within an SSIS module using C# code to attempt to deserialize a SOAP XML stream. I have been able to deserialize XML streams before, but this one is significantly more complicated than the previous ones I have been involved with.

I have verified that the string I am using to populate my stream is correct for the results, and I am reaching the end of my rope.

Here is the method I am using to try to deserialize. You can see I have included several commented out sections to show some of the other methods I have used to try to make this work:

```
private Envelope GetWebServiceResultFromStream(StreamReader str)
{

    bool b = true;
    Envelope xmlResponse = null;
    String xmlPayload = "";

   //Deserialize our XML
    try
    {
        //System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter soapFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter();

        //using (Stream savestream = str.BaseStream)
        //{
        //    xmlResponse = (Envelope)soapFormatter.Deserialize(savestream);
        //}


        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer sr = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

        using (Stream savestream = str.BaseStream)
        {
            StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(savestream, Encoding.UTF8);
            xmlPayload = streamreader.ReadToEnd();

            //xmlPayload = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(xmlPayload);

            //xmlPayload = xmlPayload.Replace("&amp;", "&");
            //xmlPayload = xmlPayload.Replace("&", "&amp;");
            xmlPayload = xmlPayload.Replace("'", "&apos;");
            //xmlPayload = xmlPayload.Replace("soap:Envelope", "Envelope");


            File.WriteAllText(@"myxml.xml",xmlPayload);



            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlPayload);
            MemoryStream secondstream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            secondstream.Position = 0;

            xmlResponse = sr.Deserialize(secondstream) as Envelope;

            //xmlResponse = (Envelope)DeserializeFromXml<Envelope>(xmlPayload);

            //XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            //doc.Load(secondstream);
            //XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);
            //using (reader)
            //{
            //    xmlResponse = sr.Deserialize(reader) as Envelope;
            //}


            //System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter soapFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter();


            //xmlResponse = (Envelope)soapFormatter.Deserialize(secondstream);


        }

        //XmlDocument xmlSoapRequest = new XmlDocument();
        //using (Stream savestream = str.BaseStream)
        //{
        //    using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(savestream, Encoding.UTF8))
        //    {
        //        xmlSoapRequest.Load(readStream);
        //        xmlPayload = xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("//Envelope/Body/GetRequisitionByDateResponse/").InnerText;
        //    }
        //}

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DumpException(ex);
        this.ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(54, "", "Failed to deserialize: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException + " Source: " + ex.Source, "", 43, ref b);
    }

    return xmlResponse;

}

public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string xml)
{
    T result;

    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var tr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        result = (T)ser.Deserialize(tr);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am using c# classes generated by feeding a response into the XML to C# converter (http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/). Unfortunately it appears the classes are too complex to put here (posts have a 30k character limit), so it has been pasted here:
http://txt.do/d91eo

I also pasted an example response:
http://txt.do/d91eb

I have consulted the wsdl and it appears that many DateTime fields are being read as strings through the converter. I am not sure if this is an issue, but I have tried to do my best to replace those data types and the error persisted.

Here is a screenshot of my error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFXeV.jpg

Other things I have tried:

Replacing invalid characters throughout the xml document (I found that it is doing this already, except in the case of some of the "'" characters).

Removed namespaces.

Marked all the classes as Serializable.

The Web Services object within SSIS (throws an error and doesn't let me enter any variables to send).

Regenerated the class list with a number of variants of the return result.

Answer (score 1):

Found it

First add UTF8 to StreamReader : new StreamReader(FILENAME, Encoding.UTF8);

Here is your Root Class

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
    public class Envelope
    {
    }
```

Here is you first line of XML

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Compare Namespaces

Comment: So you are saying I should change my namespace on my Root Class to be equal to the xmlns:soap namespace? I tried that, along with the extra encoding parameter and am getting the same error. Maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes. I made the class : "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope".  Are you getting an error on column zero or column 2?  I first was getting an error on Row 1 column zero which is due to encoding.   Then I was getting  an on column 2 which was the namespace.  Afterwards I got null data in the Envelope, but Envelope was constructed.   So when you get the error is Envelope null?

Comment: The error has always been (0,0), never anything else.

w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope was what it already was, right?

Comment: To answer your other question, yes, they are null. It is throwing the error when it tries to deserialize, though.

Comment: Then make sure you use : StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(savestream, Encoding.UTF8);  Also try to open the file with NotePad.  Then do SaveAs and don't save.  But make sure the file type is UTF8 (not ANSI, Unicode, nor Unicode Big Endian).

Comment: StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(savestream, Encoding.UTF8);

That is present in my code. I don't really know what I am doing that is different from what you are telling me. You said to change the namespace on the root class, but then said to change it to the same one it already was? Just the encoding change does not fix the issue.

Comment: Related to the idea of opening my xml in notepad, it does say it is UTF-8.

Comment: FYI I have edited my code above to reflect the new encoding being added to the StreamReader.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is running without exceptions.  I can't include class because of size limitation.  Note the namespace for Class Envelope I replaced "-" with "/".  The class Envelope is constructed but all properties are null's because the namespace don't agree with the xml.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication50
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Test();

        }
    }
    public class Test
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        public Test()
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME, Encoding.UTF8);
            GetWebServiceResultFromStream(reader);
        }

        private Envelope GetWebServiceResultFromStream(StreamReader str)
        {

            bool b = true;
            Envelope xmlResponse = null;
            String xmlPayload = "";

           //Deserialize our XML
            try
            {
                //System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter soapFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter();

                //using (Stream savestream = str.BaseStream)
                //{
                //    xmlResponse = (Envelope)soapFormatter.Deserialize(savestream);
                //}


                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer sr = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

                using (Stream savestream = str.BaseStream)
                {
                    StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(savestream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    xmlPayload = streamreader.ReadToEnd();

                    //xmlPayload = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(xmlPayload);

                    //xmlPayload = xmlPayload.Replace("&amp;", "&");
                    //xmlPayload = xmlPayload.Replace("&", "&amp;");
                    xmlPayload = xmlPayload.Replace("'", "&apos;");
                    //xmlPayload = xmlPayload.Replace("soap:Envelope", "Envelope");


                    File.WriteAllText(@"myxml.xml",xmlPayload);



                    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlPayload);
                    MemoryStream secondstream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                    secondstream.Position = 0;

                    xmlResponse = sr.Deserialize(secondstream) as Envelope;

                    //xmlResponse = (Envelope)DeserializeFromXml<Envelope>(xmlPayload);

                    //XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    //doc.Load(secondstream);
                    //XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);
                    //using (reader)
                    //{
                    //    xmlResponse = sr.Deserialize(reader) as Envelope;
                    //}


                    //System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter soapFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter();


                    //xmlResponse = (Envelope)soapFormatter.Deserialize(secondstream);


                }

                //XmlDocument xmlSoapRequest = new XmlDocument();
                //using (Stream savestream = str.BaseStream)
                //{
                //    using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(savestream, Encoding.UTF8))
                //    {
                //        xmlSoapRequest.Load(readStream);
                //        xmlPayload = xmlSoapRequest.SelectSingleNode("//Envelope/Body/GetRequisitionByDateResponse/").InnerText;
                //    }
                //}

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                //DumpException(ex);
                //this.ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(54, "", "Failed to deserialize: " + ex.Message + " Inner: " + ex.InnerException + " Source: " + ex.Source, "", 43, ref b);
            }

            return xmlResponse;

        }

        public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string xml)
        {
            T result;

            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var tr = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                result = (T)ser.Deserialize(tr);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soap", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Soap { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsd { get; set; }
    }



}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this in the morning.

Comment: Also make sure the xml starts at first character in file with no spaces before the opening angle bracket.

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists at 0,0 even with the above copied in exactly. I have also verified there is no space before the xml.

Comment: I would to recopy xml from same location that I did on the webpage to make sure there are not difference.  Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Did you use the Envelope class in the above code or did you use yours?  The class above works for me.

Comment: I copied the envelope class from above, yes.

Comment: I'm sure the problem has something do with how we are using different XML sources... I provided the sample xml that was provided to me by the service, but the actual xml I am trying to decode is far more lengthy, and obviously different in some way. I can't provide the real xml unfortunately as it is loaded with confidential information.

Comment: It looks like the sample and actual xml have different namespaces.  I assume my code works with the sample.  So you have to change the namespace when using the actual file so the class and the xml are consistent with the namespace.

Comment: This is the Envelope line I get back from the actual response:

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

Comment: Thank you for your continued attention to this, by the way.

Comment: So this should be changes and include the slash at end From : [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")] To:

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/")]

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same error, even with the slash.

Comment: I just tried an experiment and took the soap response and put it in the test xml.  Also made the class consistent and it doesn't work.  So lets try the opposite.  Take the actual xml and replace the soap-envelope with soap/envelope.  Also change class to use the forward slash.  I think there is something wrong with the schema webpage (namespace).

Comment: I am not 100% sure I follow, but I tried. This is the class:

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/envelope/")]

And this is the xml response, edited:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetRequisitionByDateResponse xmlns="http://services.printable.com/1.0/requisition"> . It threw the same error.

Comment: By the way stackoverflow is taking out the "http: //www ." but they are there

Comment: I just noticed that this follows that first part of the real xml response:

<soap:Body><GetRequisitionByDateResponse xmlns="http://services.printable.com/1.0/requisition"><GetRequisitionByDateResult xmlns="http://www.printable.com/sso"><GetRequisitionsResponse xmlns="">

Might it have something to do with that blank namespace for GetRequisitionsResponse?

Comment: We should take one class at a time.  Right now all I care about is getting a response without error.  It doesn't matter if you have www.w3 or just w3.  Also see if you are getting error at 0,0 or 0,2 there is a difference.  I plan to try some more things over the weekend.

Comment: It is still 0,0.